# I need loose minifigures

Tags: minifigures

I need the joints of my minifigures to be extremely loose. So loose that they cannot stand for a comedy sketch. I’ve tried almost everything at this point.

Comment: Could you list some of the options you have already tried?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [How can I loosen my Minifigures arms and legs](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/15047/56)

Comment: We shouldn't mark this a dupe and close that other question.  For potential answers it is hard to tell which question is viable moving forward, at this stage.

Comment: When a mummy minifig and a daddy needle file love each other very much....

Comment: @chicks The other has better answers than this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I loosen my Minifigures arms and legs?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/15047/how-can-i-loosen-my-minifigures-arms-and-legs)

Answer (score 0):

This recommendation is a bit time consuming: fiddle about with it a lot and it wil loosen.